# Picking up a key from an opened drawer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

So I have got a drawer that is animated with a script that shows a panel to prompt the player to open/close the drawer using a trigger. I have also got a key with a similar script on it, but instead, it prompts the player to pick up the key also using a panel and triggers. I would like to place the key in the drawer, so when the player presses 'E' to open the drawer, they can also press 'E' to pick up the key. I have tried making the drawer's collider smaller and also made the key collider bigger but that just means the player can pick up the key without opening the drawer. What is a more effective way of achieving this? I will also attach my code if needed.

DrawerScript:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class DrawerScript : MonoBehaviour
{

UnityEvent Event = new UnityEvent();

public GameObject OpenPanel = null;

private bool _isInsideTrigger = false;

public Animator _animator;

public string OpenText = "Press 'E' to open drawer";

public string CloseText = "Press 'E' to close drawer";

private bool _isOpen = false;

private void Start()
{
    OpenPanel.SetActive(false);
}


void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        _isInsideTrigger = true;
        OpenPanel.SetActive(true);
        UpdatePanelText();
        Event.Invoke();
    }
}

private void UpdatePanelText()
{
    Text panelText = OpenPanel.transform.Find("Text").GetComponent<Text>();
    if (panelText != null)
    {
        panelText.text = _isOpen ? CloseText: OpenText;
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        _isInsideTrigger = false;
        OpenPanel.SetActive(false);
    }
}

private bool IsOpenPanelActive
{
    get
    {
        return OpenPanel.activeInHierarchy;
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (IsOpenPanelActive && _isInsideTrigger)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            _isOpen = !_isOpen;

            Invoke ("UpdatePanelText", 1.0f);

            _animator.SetBool("open", _isOpen);
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Key Pickup Script:

```
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class PickUp : MonoBehaviour
 {

public Collider Collider;

public GameObject OpenPanel = null;

private bool _isInsideTrigger = false;


public string PickUpText = "Press 'E' to pick up";

private void Start()
{
    if (OpenPanel != null)
    {
        OpenPanel.SetActive(false);
    }
    Collider = GetComponent<Collider>();
}


void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        _isInsideTrigger = true;
        OpenPanel.SetActive(true);
        UpdatePanelText();
    }
}

private void UpdatePanelText()
{
    Text panelText = OpenPanel.transform.Find("Text").GetComponent<Text>();
    if (panelText != null)
    {
        panelText.text = PickUpText;
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        _isInsideTrigger = false;
        OpenPanel.SetActive(false);
    }
}

private bool IsOpenPanelActive
{
    get
    {
        return OpenPanel.activeInHierarchy;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about checking if the drawer is open before picking up the key..?

Comment: @RufusL Don't let them pick up the key unless the drawer is open. Then again, you might have problems if they want to just close the drawer without picking up the key. Since both actions are with `E`.

Comment: Well, you already have the script that calls the animation whenever the player presses "E" on the drawer, you could subscribe the key to an UnityEvent on the drawer that invokes when user presses E. This could be achieved with addlistener and a callback function. On this function you could then enable or disable the keys box collider.

Comment: @Jimenemex That's the issue I had, but I want the interaction key to be E.

Comment: @VitorFigueredo how would I implement this, I checked the API but I don't get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use UnityEvent API.

It's not the best solution and there are several ways to do that but if you are trying to solve the problem quickly you could, for example, create a UnityEvent inside your drawer class.

You need to add the namespace:

```
using UnityEngine.Events;
```

and, as a variable:

```
UnityEvent event = new UnityEvent();
```

This will probably create a new event (very similar to a button) on your drawer class. Next step is creating a method that will enable or disable the collider, inside your key class. The method must me public.

After that, simply go to your drawer GameObject click on the "+" sign, drag your Key GameObject to it and select the class and the public method you just created. This will subscribe that method to the event.

Lastly, on your "open drawer" method, you simply call:

```
event.Invoke();
```

And everyone "listening" to it will be executed, including your class.

Comment: Even though I'm not a very strong coder, I tried to implement it like to the best of my abilities but I'm getting weird results. Here I edited the post and added my scripts and implementations, please have a look.